# How to configure WCF Service with Https WindowsAuthentication?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am trying to figure it out how to set configurations on my service and Silverlight client App to work on Secure Windows Authentication.

I have my service configured like this:

```
    <binding name="currentCustomBinding">

      <binaryMessageEncoding />

      <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" />

    </binding>

  </customBinding>
```

```
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="True" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />

    </behavior>

  <service name=" OperationService" behaviorConfiguration=" OperationServiceBehavior">

    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration=" OperationServiceBehavior" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="currentCustomBinding" contract="OperationService" />

  </service>
```

Any ideas? 10q